# Loop for en iteración de DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un script que itera un archivo y funciona perfecto y es el siguiente:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from datetime import datetime
import re
from pathlib import Path
import os
import pandas as pd


ruta = Path("E:\Python\Visual Studio Code Proyects\M2M Real\Archivos\Router A - show interfaces description pipe include Gi0-3-4-3.txt")
ruta2 = Path("E:\Python\Visual Studio Code Proyects\M2M Real\Archivos\\")

with open(ruta, "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open(ruta, "w") as fw:
    for line in lines:
        if not re.match("-{5}|\s+|([A-Za-z0-9]+( [A-Za-z0-9]+)+)", line):
            fw.write(line)

csv_name2 = f'{ruta2}\{ruta.stem}.csv'
csv_name3 = f'{ruta2}\{ruta.stem}.xlsx'


df = pd.read_fwf(ruta)

df["Description"] = (df.iloc[:, 3:].fillna("").astype(str).apply(" ".join, axis=1).str.strip())

df = df.iloc[:, :4]

df = df.drop(columns = ["Status", "Protocol"])

df.Interface = df.Interface.str.extract('Gi0/3/4/3\.(\d+)')

df = df[df.Interface.notnull()].reset_index()

df = df.drop(columns = ["index"])

df['Interface'] = df['Interface'].astype(int)

df = df.set_index('Interface').reindex(range(1,3580)).fillna('free').reset_index()

print(df)

def is_free(valor):
    color = 'green' if valor == "free"  else 'white'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color

df = df.style.applymap(is_free)

df = df.to_excel(csv_name3, sheet_name='Router A - Gi0-3-4-3', index=False)
```

este es el archivo txt original:

```
Interface          Status      Protocol    Description
Gi0/3/4/3          up          up          ENLACE A Router B
Gi0/3/4/3.401      up          up          Frontera Cliente A
Gi0/3/4/3.402      up          up          Frontera Cliente B
Gi0/3/4/3.403      up          up          Frontera Cliente C
Gi0/3/4/3.404      up          up          Frontera Cliente D
etc....
```

y el xlsx finalmente se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es cuando intento hacer un loop for para iterar sobre varios archivos TXT que me empieza a tirar mil errores como si fuese un loop while abierto.

Intenté armar esto pero que es lo que falla:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from datetime import datetime
import re
from pathlib import Path
import os
import pandas as pd

ruta = Path("E:\Python\Visual Studio Code Proyects\M2M Real\Archivos")

def is_free(valor):
    color = 'green' if valor == "free"  else 'white'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color

list_txt = [ruta/"Router_a.txt", ruta/"Router_b.txt"]

for txt in list_txt:

  with open(txt, "r") as f:

    lines = f.readlines()

  with open(txt, "w") as fw:
    for line in lines:

      if not re.match("-{5}|\s+|([A-Za-z0-9]+( [A-Za-z0-9]+)+)", line):
        fw.write(line)

for txt in list_txt:

  host = txt.stem

  ruta_host = f'{ruta}\\interfaces.xlsx'

  df = pd.read_fwf(txt)

  df["Description"] = (df.iloc[:, 3:].fillna("").astype(str).apply(" ".join, axis=1).str.strip())

  df = df.iloc[:, :4]

  df = df.drop(columns = ["Status", "Protocol"])

  df.Interface = df.Interface.str.extract('Gi0/3/4/2\.(\d+)')

  df = df[df.Interface.notnull()].reset_index()

  df = df.drop(columns = ["index"])

  df = df['Interface'] = df['Interface'].astype(int)

  df = df.set_index('Interface').reindex(range(1,3580)).fillna('free').reset_index()

  df = df.style.applymap(is_free)

  df = df.to_excel(ruta_host, sheet_name=f'{host} - Gi0-3-4-2', index=False)
```

En principio por algún extraño motivo me lanza un error en la línea

```
  df = df.set_index('Interface').reindex(range(1,3580)).fillna('free').reset_index()
```

pero si comento esa línea tanto como la siguiente empieza a tirar millones de errores.

¿Alguna idea de qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

**AUTORESPUESTA**

```
df = df['Interface'] = df['Interface'].astype(int)
```

Finalmente hay un doble = que traia el problema.

Aun asi cuando sigue iterando y creando el archivo correctamente no logro generar multiples hojas, itera el primer archivo de TXT, genera la hoja correctamente pero nunca genera la segunda hoja.

Alguna idea de por que no crea la segunda hoja?

Comment: Hablaste varias veces de errores, pero no mencionaste cuáles. Pulsá en [edit] y mostrá los errores, _como texto, con formato_. Leé [ask].

Comment: Como estas Padaleiana? No creo q sea de gran ayuda porque como ya comente, me da una lista interminable de errores porque empieza a iterar dentro del loop como loco hasta q corta solo con un "maximum recursion depth exceeded" esta claro q el loop esta mal planteado y la pregunta apunta a alguien q sepa mas q uno que pueda ayudar a ver el error en la estructura de lo q intento hacer. Saludos!

Comment: Claro que seria de ayuda Martin, quizas no toda la traza pero una cantidad considerada de lineas para ver que esta pasando en tu codigo!

Comment: Listo, encontre el error pero aun asi no logro el resultado final de lo que pretendo, en principio el error era el siguiente:

    **df = df['Interface'] = df['Interface'].astype(int)**

 tenia un doble =, pero no logro poder generar una hoja por cada vuelta del loop for, es decir me genera la primera hoja y ahi finaliza todo.